# Ao utilizar back() no laravel este deve ser precedido por redirect()?

Tags: laravel

Observando muitas implementações vi que o pessoal utiliza com uma certa frequência `return redirect()->back()`... Minha dúvida é:

Qual a diferença entre `return redirect()->back()`... e `return back()`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essas são duas formas de fazer a mesma coisa, ou seja, *redirecionar para o local anterior* e são funções que retornam a instância da classe `Redirector` e tem como principal objetivo facilitar no desenvolvimento.

***Estruturas:***

`back()`

```
function back($status = 302, $headers = [], $fallback = false)
{
    return app('redirect')->back($status, $headers, $fallback);
}
```

`redirect()`

```
function redirect($to = null, $status = 302, $headers = [], $secure = null)
{
    if (is_null($to)) {
        return app('redirect');
    }

    return app('redirect')->to($to, $status, $headers, $secure);
}
```

Sobre as estruturas, é que o `redirect` pode chamar os outros métodos, enquanto `back()` já seria a chamada do método, as duas formas são corretas, mas, a `back()` nesse caso é que se encaixa melhor.